# Need help on Facebook API how to get data from array with multiple fields

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

```
  $endpointFormat = ENDPOINT_BASE . '{page-id}?fields=about,bio,description,new_like_count,talking_about_count,category,fan_count,link,name,rating_count,website,whatsapp_number,followers_count,country_page_likes,were_here_count,location&access_token={access-token}';
$statsAccountEndpoint = ENDPOINT_BASE . $pageId;

$statParams = array(
    array ('fields' => 'about','bio','description','new_like_count', 'talking_about_count','category', 'fan_count', 'link','name','rating_count','website','whatsapp_number','followers_count','country_page_likes','were_here_count','location'),
    'access_token' => $singleRow['fbaccesstoken']
);

// add params to endpoint
$statsAccountEndpoint .= '?' . http_build_query( $statParams );

// setup curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $statsAccountEndpoint );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

// make call and get response
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
$responseArray = json_decode( $response, true );
```

Printing out the statParams
[image: Printing out the statParams =]

Printing out responseArray which only shows the name and page id

[image]

Just wanting to get the stats of the page im linking, tried with only 1 field variable before and it showed fine. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $statParams = array(
    'fields' => 'about,bio,description,new_like_count,talking_about_count,category,fan_count,link,name,rating_count,website,whatsapp_number,followers_count,country_page_likes,were_here_count,location',
);
```

just had to make it so that everything is in one big '' instead of separate.